# sql to update table for multiple columns.?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have an EMP table with columns like id,name,job,salary,age,doj.
This EMP table has 10 records, with IDs id1,id2....id10.

I need a DML statement to update names for 4 IDs ( id2,id4, id6, id8). 
This requires multiple where conditions.
Such as -
     name=a where id=id2
     name=b where id=id4.

Please suggest.

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression. That should look like:

```
update emp
set name = case id
    when 'id2' then 'a'
    when 'id4' then 'b'
    when 'id6' then 'c'
    when 'id8' then 'd'
end
where id in ('id2', 'id4', 'id6', 'id8')
```

Comment: @ManjunathM: what is the datatype of column `id`?

Comment: id is varchar2 and name is long type

Comment: @ManjunathM: OK. The query shouldn't raise this error (there are not numbers involved here). Please run the query exactly as provided.